# Can't find children of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

for some reason i'm unable to get the children from the div with the classname of `.slideshow-dots`. Here is the div with it's children:

```
<div class="slideshow-dots">
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

And this is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

Below is my code, i'm also unable to call the public method `showSlides`.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.MarvSimpleGallery = function( options ) {
      var instance = this;
      instance.index = 1;

      var settings = $.extend({
        // These are the defaults.
        arrows: true,
        dots: true,
        numbers: true
      }, options );

      var init = function() {
        instance.dotCont = instance.find('.slideshow-dots')[0];
        instance.slides = instance.find('.mySlides');

        // Assign event listeners
        instance.find('.prev').click(function() { instance.showSlides(instance.index += -1); });
        instance.find('.next').click(function() { instance.showSlides(instance.index += 1); });

        // Initiate dot controls
        $.each(instance.slides, function(index, data) {
          var dot = $('<span></span>');
          dot.addClass('dot');
          dot.click(function() { instance.showSlides(instance.index = (index + 1)); });

          $(instance.dotCont).append(dot); 
        });

        // Show initial slide


      }();

      instance.showSlides = function(n) {
        console.log('Slide: ' + n);
        if (n > (instance.slides).length) instance.index = 1;
        if (n < 1) instance.index = (instance.slides).length;

        var slideCount = (instance.slides).length;

        $.each(instance.slides, function(index, data) {
          data.style.display = "none";
          $(data).prepend($('<div></div>').addClass('numbertext').append((index + 1) + ' / ' + slideCount));
        });

        instance.slides[instance.index-1].style.display = "block"; 
        $(instance.dotCont).find('dots')[instance.index-1].className += " active";
      };

    }
  }(jQuery));
```

Comment: At some point, `instance.index-1` is not a valid key for the collection on the last line of your code. Share a working example (jsfiddle, stacksnippets, codepen....)

Comment: Could you help us out and give us a hint as to as to which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Another question: why you mix vanilla JS with jQuery?

Comment: `find('dots')` -> `find('.dots')`

Comment: And the last thing, I guess the problem: `$(instance.dotCont).find('.dot')` you miss a dot inside the find function and a `s` more!!

Comment: I'm an idiot, `find('.dot')` worked, I simply wasn't selection my children elements correctly :/ Also, im just using what I know and not sure what jQuery replaces the vanilla JS i'm using.

Comment: Any idea on my other issue, if I try and call `instance.showSlides(instance.index = 1);` within the init function I get an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: instance.showSlides is not a function` @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: Before posting a question, you must to identify the problem first. If you see an error on your console, you must interpret the meaning because on the 80% of the cases the problem is insignificant, or typographycal

Comment: This is from stackoverflow help: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @MartynBall that function is declared after the call. So the function doesn't exists when you call it. Declare functions as `function XXX () {}` or before the call. Try to understand **hoisting** :)

Answer (score 5):

try

```
$(instance.dotCont).find('dot')[instance.index-1].className += " active";
```

instead of

```
$(instance.dotCont).find('dots')[instance.index-1].className += " active";
```

Your children elements have the class 'dot' and not 'dots'.

**Edit** - as said in comment:

i forgot the dot:
the final sentence must be

```
$(instance.dotCont).find('.dot')[instance.index-1].className += " active";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: That code will search for `<dot>` child elements, not `class=dot` child elements.